# How to prevent xcode treating <# #> as a code snippet placeholder

Tags: objective-c, xcode, token, code-snippets

I want to include <# #> in a literal string in an Objective C program. However, Xcode automatically replaces the string thinking it should be a placeholder as used in code snippets.

e.g.

```
NSString *pattern = @"<#foo#>"
```

Try putting this into Xcode and it redisplays as a placeholder for foo.

In the actual program the string is an RE like this `<#(.*)#>` and surprisingly, the code actually works as intended - the problem only manifests itself in the display in Xcode. The real problem is that this creates a fragile situation, it is far too easy to cause the text to be replaced accidentally when in the editor.

As a workaround I can construct the string from it's parts

```
NSString *p1 = @"<#(.*)";
NSString *p2 = @"#>";
NSString *pattern = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",p1,p2];
```

but that is not very satisfactory.

Does anyone know a better way to override this behaviour in Xcode?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can avoid the bad behavior by taking advantage of string concatenation, e.g.

```
NSString *str = @"<" "#foo#" ">";
```

Comment: @Tommy Xcode doesn't seem to care either way, and it's cleaner without all the extra '@'s.

Comment: Then I guess I'm behind on Objective-C syntax changes. You got my +1 regardless.

Comment: You can concatenate Objective-C literal strings and C literal strings in this manner. Based on a test I just did, I believe it always uses the type of the first element.

Answer (score 2):

Swift 4, Xcode 9 - you just need to separate out or replace one character to make the sequence work. Still not perfect...

string concatenation:

```
let pattern = "<" + "#foo#>"
```

string interpolation:

```
let pattern = "\("<")#foo#>"
```

percent encoding:

```
let pattern = "%003c#foo#>".removingPercentEncoding
```

Funny fact: printing the pattern to the console displays as a placeholder, `foo`.

Not so funny fact: you can't print the pattern to a log. Since it's created via concatenation or other runtime processing, it doesn't meet the `StaticString` type required in a log message.

**Update:** you *can* use the pattern in a log (though, again, it displays as a placeholder - argh!). To get past the `StaticString` issue, you can use `%@` in your log statement:

```
let pattern = "<" + "#foo#>" // or whichever version you like best
os_log("%@", log: .default, type: .debug, pattern)
```